# How does memoize interact with binding in Clojure?

Tags: performance, clojure

Does `memoize` keep track of changes to binding which may make returning a computation it has stored incorrect?

For example if I have a function foo such as:

```
(defn foo [bar baz]
 ...
   (let [config-val *config-val*]
    ...)
 )
```

which I contain within a binding so I can change the value of `*config-val*`, does memoizing it mean that if I change the value of `*config-val*`, but not the parameters to it that it will not recompute the value of the function? Instead it will give me the value of the function with the old configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Clojure 1.3.0 `memoize` doesn't keep track of rebinding.

```
user=> (def ^:dynamic *x* 5)
#'user/*x*
user=> (def f (memoize #(+ *x* %)))
#'user/f
user=> (f 1)
6
user=> (binding [*x* 6] (f 1))
6
user=> (binding [*x* 7] (f 1))
6
```

Additionally,

```
user=> (binding [*x* 7] (f 3))
10
user=> (f 3)
10
user=> *x*
5
```

Answer (score 2):

`memoize` does not account for binding, this can be confirmed by looking at the source where the map in the atom is keyed only by the arguments. Indeed a function with dynamic rebinding is not "referentially transparent" (i.e. it cannot be replaced with its value).

Is there something that prevents you from passing the `*config-val*` as an argument, at least to the function you wish to memoize?

```
user=> (source memoize)
(defn memoize
  "Returns a memoized version of a referentially transparent function. The
  memoized version of the function keeps a cache of the mapping from arguments
  to results and, when calls with the same arguments are repeated often, has
  higher performance at the expense of higher memory use."
  {:added "1.0"}
  [f]
  (let [mem (atom {})]
    (fn [& args]
      (if-let [e (find @mem args)]
        (val e)
        (let [ret (apply f args)]
          (swap! mem assoc args ret)
          ret)))))
```

Comment: Not really I just trying to work out ways to restructure this, I've gotten some nice working code, I'm just trying to think of ways of making it a lot faster.

Answer (score 2):

As the [documentation for memoize](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/memoize) suggests, a memoized function will keep an internal cache of arguments mapping to results. When a memoized function is called with arguments it has already seen it will do nothing but look up the correct return value from the cache. Nothing will be recomputed and you will get the same result as you got the last time you called the function. Any rebindings will be ignored.

```
user=> (def ^:dynamic op +)
user=> (defn add [x y] (op x y))
user=> (add 1 2)
3
user=> (binding [op -]
         (add 1 2))
-1
user=> (alter-var-root #'add memoize)
user=> (add 1 2)
3
user=> (binding [op -]
         (add 1 2))
3
```